# Send Keys & AppActivate

Tags: excel, vba, keyevent, sendkeys, active-window

**Method:**

I'm using a combination of SendKeys & Virtual Keyboard to send key strokes to a core administration system that is stored on Citrix as an application. The VBA code is identifying the application by using the AppActivate & Application.ActiveWindow methods.

**Goal:**

My goal is to have an user to input data into an excel spreadsheet and send the data to the core administration system using VBA in lieu of the user manually keying.

**Problem:**

My problems are many, but as of right now, I'm struggling to send Ctrl + f to the core administration system application. It doesn't seem to recognize the stroke, however, sending f alone or enter "keybd_event VK_RETURN, mvk, 0, 0" seems to work. Also, "keybd_event VK_CONTROL, mvk, 0, 0" seemed promising but I get an "Overflow" error when ran.

**Code (So Far):**

```
Option Explicit


Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, 
ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MapVirtualKey Lib "user32" Alias " 
MapVirtualKeyA" (ByVal wCode As Long, ByVal wMapType As Long) As Long
Private Const VK_RETURN = &HD
Private Const VK_CONTROL = &HD11
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2



Sub pleasework5()

Dim keys As String
Dim wsh As Object
Dim mvk As Double

Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
mvk = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, 0)
AppActivate ("application name") 'use form to enter username
Application.ActiveWindow.Activate
Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
'keybd_event VK_CONTROL, mvk, 0, 0
wsh.SendKeys ("^f"), True
```

Please let me know how to send Ctrl + f to the system application or if there's a better method of going about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you've found the solution by now. However, here's what I do to send Ctrl + L

```
SendKeys "(^l)"
```

Hope that helps